# WordPress: Get Yoast SEO title for custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, yoast

I'm trying to get the SEO title from a custom taxonomy.

Here's my current code for it:

```
$my_yoast_wpseo_title = get_term_meta( $term_id, '_wpseo_title', true );
if( $my_yoast_wpseo_title ){
    echo $my_yoast_wpseo_title;
} else {
    echo 'No title';
}
```

It doesn't work.

So I tried different meta keys like `_yoast_wpseo_title` and everything I could find in their docs and other snippets.

Nothing works.

So I checked the complete output of `get_term_meta`. Like this:

```
$my_yoast_wpseo_title = get_term_meta( $term_id );
print_r($my_yoast_wpseo_title);
```

It shows a lot of meta fields. But the Yoast meta isn't stored there?!
Is their any other place?

The taxonomy has a custom SEO title and shows it in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yoast SEO Titles for Terms are stored in the `options` table.

This will at least give you the idea you're after.

```
$options = get_option( 'wpseo_taxonomy_meta' );
// $options will be an array of taxonomies where the taxonomy name is the array key.
$term_id = get_queried_object_id();
foreach ( $options['your_term_here'] as $id => $option ) {
    if ( $term_id === $id ) {
        /* This returns an array with the following keys
            'wpseo_title'
            'wpseo_focuskw'
            'wpseo_linkdex'
        */      
        echo ( ! empty( $option['wpseo_title'] ) ) ? $option['wpseo_title'] : 'no title';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found another solution based on `WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta`. I added that as additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to do this:

```
$my_yoast_wpseo_title = WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta::get_term_meta($id, 'produkt_vendor', 'title');
if( $my_yoast_wpseo_title ){
    echo $my_yoast_wpseo_title;
} else {
    echo 'No title';
}
```

You can used that with `title` and `desc` without the prefix `wpseo_`

Answer (score 1):

```
$term = get_queried_object(); 
$options = get_option( 'wpseo_taxonomy_meta' );
echo $options[$term->taxonomy][$term->term_id]['wpseo_title']; //Meta Title
echo $options[$term->taxonomy][$term->term_id]['wpseo_title']; //Meta Description
```

This is another solution to get the meta title and meta description out of yoast seo in the taxonomy. Paste this code into archive.php or taxonomy.php of your theme.